# Prove that if f is continuous everywhere, then |f| is continuous everywhere.

Tags: calculus

I don't know how to apply ||a|-|b||<|a-b| well.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is continuous everywhere.  Then that means something specific in terms of $\epsilon$'s, $c$'s, and so on.  Now... for the same choice of $\epsilon$, $\delta$ and $c$, consider $||f(c)|-|f(x)||$ and notice that the property you mention tells us something about its relationship to $|f(c)-f(x)|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, it's literally the reverse triangle inequality, like you said.

Given $x$, since $f$ is continuous, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

But $\left||f(x)|-|f(y)|\right|\le |f(x)-f(y)|$ so we are done.